# java-8 optional double checking

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I like java-8's optional chaning style.
So I want check double null.

```
class A {
    public String getSome() {
        return ""; // some string
    }
}

class B {
    public String getSome() {
        return ""; // some string
    }
}
class T {
    A a;
    B b;

    public String result() {
        if (a.getSome() != null) {
            if (b.getSome() != null) {
                return a+b;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I convert `T.result()` to Optional Style?

I tried this style but IDE told me 'cyclic interface'.

```
public String result() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(a.getSome())
                .map(a -> {
                    return Optional.ofNullable(b.getSome())
                            .map(b -> {
                                return a + b;
                            })
                            .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
                })
                .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with `if(a.getSome() != null && b.getSome() != null) {return a+b;}else{throw new RuntimeException();}`. This all seems seems to overcomplicated.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I just want to know how to convert optional style :)

Comment: I don’t get the purpose of that code. Is it about trying to avoid a `NullPointerException` in order to throw a meaningless `RuntimeException`? Besides that, there is nothing wrong with your code. You may ask the authors of the IDE what there  'cyclic interface' message is supposed to mean.

Comment: As pointed out by me and a response of @MarkoTopolnik both examples are not the same, because in the first one you return `a+b` and in the second `a.getSome()+b.getSome()`. Could you please clarify, what code you actually want, because this makes a difference in the possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

While @Eran gave a possible solution, I don't think you add simplicity by using chaining and Optionals.

The new Java 8 API and features must not be a replacement for all pre-Java 8 code. There's a lot of questions for example about using `Stream` to perform some tasks while a simple for loop would do the trick.

In your case since you only want to check if the reference is not `null`, simply do:

```
public String result() {
    return Objects.requireNonNull(a.getSome()) + Objects.requireNonNull(b.getSome());   
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing as the OPs code, because it adds up `a.getSome()+b.getSome()` in the happy path whereas the OPs code does `a+b`.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker It's not possible to do `a+b`; so I assumed the goal was to concatenate the Strings.

Comment: That would be the right thing as it flags an encounter of `null` with `NullPointerException` but for whatever reason the OP seems to intend to throw a meaningless `RuntimeException` instead. So maybe you should wrap it with `try { … } catch(NullPointerException ex) { throw new RuntimeException("guess what happened"); }` to make it complete ;-)

Comment: @SpaceTrucker If you take time to carefully examine OP's Optional-based code, you'll realize that it actually returns `a.getSome()+b.getSome()`. Pay special attention to the names of lambda parameters.

Answer (score 2):

This should be much simpler :

```
public String result() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(a.getSome()).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new) +
           Optional.ofNullable(b.getSome()).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
}
```

And if you change the `getSome` methods to return an `Optional<String>`, the result method would be even simpler :

```
public String result() {
    return a.getSome().orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new) +
           b.getSome().orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
}
```

However, if it's possible that either `a` or `b` themselves would be `null`, you need some extra code to handle that.

Comment: You can simply use [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) instead of `.orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new)`. Who cares whether the thrown exception is `NoSuchElementException` or exactly `RuntimeException` as both are `RuntimeException`s.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your method in what you call "Optional style" would result in the following monstrosity:

```
Optional.ofNullable(a.getSome())
  .flatMap(x -> 
    Optional.ofNullable(b.getSome()).map(x::concat)
  ).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new)
```

Why in the world would you want to do this?  You are trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.  Please just follow ZouZou's suggestion and use `requireNonNull`, but put each `requireNonNull` in a separate line to make stack traces easier to decipher.

What your IDE complained about is probably your use of `a` and `b` as both variables in the method and also as parameter names in the lambdas.  You are not allowed to do that.